# Delegate the business logic to another process in Spring Boot REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have `@SpringBootApplication` with `@RestController` handling `@GetMapping("/math/square")` endpoint.

For example, request `GET /math/square?x=2` returns `{result:4}`

I'd like to delegate the math business logic to another process, separated from the endpoint.

What is a recommended way to do it in Spring?

Comment: What do you mean by another "process"? Another thread, another JVM, another process in the same machine, in another machine, etc, etc?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've gathered, you want the math business logic to happen asynchronously.
Firstly, if you're not doing it for "educational purposes" or if the actual logic isn't time-consuming, then I would advise against doing that because for me it's premature optimization.

I took a look at your profile and it seems that the dominant tag is the Go language, so maybe that's why you've written "process". But I'd say that spawning another process would be too heavyweight (and cumbersome). In my opinion, executing the logic in a separate thread is a much better choice.

One way in which you can approach this in Spring is using the DeferredResult class. It serves as a container for an ongoing computation. You can return an object of this class from the controller without blocking the http-worker thread that handles the request and have the computation complete in the background. I think it's best explained with a simple example.

```
@RestController
public class MathController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MathController.class);

    @GetMapping(value = "/math/square")
    public DeferredResult<Integer> computeSquare(@RequestParam("x") int x) {
        logger.info("Delegating the computation to another thread");
        DeferredResult<Integer> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();

        new Thread(() -> { // normally, you would probably use a thread pool
            // here's where the "heavy logic" takes place
            logger.info("Computing the square of {}", x);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // let's say that it takes some time for demonstration purposes
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            logger.info("Setting the result");
            deferredResult.setResult(x * x);
        }).start();

        logger.info("Done handling the request");
        return deferredResult;
    }
}
```

By looking at sample logging statements, we can confirm that the http-worker thread (nio-8080-exec-1) didn't wait for the computation to finish. And of course, the client that sent the GET request will get the result as the HTTP connection remains open until `deferredResult` is resolved.

```
2018-06-22 01:05:02.146  INFO 13144 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.s.s.controllers.MathController       : Delegating the computation to another thread
2018-06-22 01:05:02.154  INFO 13144 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.e.s.s.controllers.MathController       : Done handling the request
2018-06-22 01:05:02.154  INFO 13144 --- [      Thread-14] c.e.s.s.controllers.MathController       : Computing the square of 2
2018-06-22 01:05:03.156  INFO 13144 --- [      Thread-14] c.e.s.s.controllers.MathController       : Setting the result
```